# Why am I getting this warning `No duplicate props allowed react/jsx-no-duplicate-props`

Tags: react-redux

Why am I getting this warning?

> warning  No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props#

It's showing line number 28 but there is nothing props is using.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You probably passed the same prop twice to a Component. e.g.

```
<MyComponent someProp={'a'} someProp={'b'} />
```

Comment: u meant am passing same  props  twice to a component .?

Comment: Yes, I encountered this error recently and that was my cause

Comment: i'm using Material UI and i am getting this error for InputProps and inputProps which is not the same (Capital I and small letter i)  what can i do ?

Comment: I added `onHandleInputChange={}`props twice without knowing it. The accepted solution is still working. Thanks!

Comment: lol thanks! I just got this warning and i was confused why is it coming... but this answer literally helped me

Comment: i'm confused in , does this occur also due to rendering the component two times in different js files ?
 like
<MyComponent someProp={'a'}  /> in index.js,     
<MyComponent someProp={b'}  /> in xyz.js

Comment: @D p, that I don't think so.

Answer (score 16):

I also go this error, I was rendering a component and passed 'className' twice. My solution was found here with [How to apply multiple classnames to an element](https://github.com/rtsao/csjs/wiki/How-to-apply-multiple-classnames-to-an-element). I then just concated the names together, the error went away and my UI rendered perfectly.

//Error

```js
<IconButton
  color="secondary"
  className={classes.button}
  className={classes.test}
  component="span"
  classes={{
    root: classes.checkRoot,
  }}
>
```

//Solution

```js
<IconButton
 color="secondary"
 className={[classes.button, classes.test ]}
 component="span"
 classes={{
    root: classes.checkRoot,
 }}
>
```

Comment: as simple as that :)) I wasted my time about a few days actually! but I couldn't find the problem! thank you <3

Answer (score 13):

Regarding uppercase/lowercase problems with Material-UI [TextField](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api), a component that takes `inputProps` and `InputProps`, I didn't want ESLint to output a warning for this, so I added this to my .eslintrc.json file:

```
"rules": {
    "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": [1, { "ignoreCase": false }]
  }
```

Comment: This was exactly the issue I had with the MUI `TextField`. Oddly enough, `false` is the default according to the docs, so we must have some other opinionated linter settings being applied. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to add rule, there is a property to set attributes `InputProps={inputProps: { maxLength }}`

Answer (score 5):

The warning come when any duplicate attribute is used on same tag i.e.

```
    <input id="a" id="b" />
    <MyComponent someProp={'a'} someProp={'b'} />
    <input placehoder="a" placeholder="a" />
    <div className='a' className='b'></div>
```

Comment: This is was my problem. Had regular links with 2 `alt=` tags.

Answer (score 1):

It can be as simple as duplicate id on HTML:

```
<input id="txt-id" id="txtID" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be one of the following:

```
<input id="a" id="b" />
<MyComponent someProp={'a'} someProp={'b'} />
<input placehoder="a" placeholder="a" />
<div className='a' className='b'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to share this since I did not see it as possible errors. But I experience this issue when I had two required on a input.

Example:

```
<input required type="email" name="form-email" required />
```

Should be:

```
  <input type="email" name="form-email" required />
```

Comment: This fixed it for me, i had double alt=""