# 'Product' s defined but never used in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, jsx

I am trying to use a higher order function to get information from another file. I have three files that i use. My SchoolProduct.js file which is an array with objects, Second is my Product.js component. This file i am using for **Props**. Third file App.js where the magic should happen. I keep getting an error. 'product' is defined but never used. I know well what it means but i keep looking into my code without any luck. I want to display all the object elements to the screen, its very simple. heres my code.

**App.js file**

```
import React from 'react'
import SchoolProducts from "./SchoolProducts.js"
import Product from "./component/Product.js"

function App() {
  const OurProducts = SchoolProducts.map(
    Product => <Product key={"1"} name={Product.name} description={Product.description}/>
  )

  return (
    <div>
      {OurProducts}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

**Product.js file**

```
import React from "react"

function Product(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{props.Product.name} </h3>
      <h3> {props.Product.price}</h3>
      <h3> {props.Product.description}</h3>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Product
```

**SchoolProducts.js file**

```
const SchoolProducts = [ {
    id: "1",
    name: "pencil",
    description: "Perfect for those who cant remember things"
},
{
    id: "2",
    name: "pencil",
    price: 1,
    description: "Perfect for those who cant remember things"

},
{
    id: "3",
    name: "pencil",
    price: 1,
    description: "Perfect for those who cant remember things"

},
{
    id: "4",
    name: "pencil",
    price: 1,
    description: "Perfect for those who cant remember things"

},
{
    id: "5",
    name: "pencil",
    price: 1,
    description: "Perfect for those who cant remember things"

}


]

export default SchoolProducts
```

Comment: A good tip to avoid this kind of problems is to [`camelCase` variables and `PascalCase` components (and usually type constructors)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1008230/1218980)

Answer (score 3):

You're using the same variable name in different scopes - the `Product` on the top level is the React component, but the `SchoolProducts` contains the array of objects, so with `SchoolProducts.map(Product =>`, inside that `.map`, `Product` refers to a plain object.

Use different variable names:

```
const OurProducts = SchoolProducts.map(SchoolProduct => (
  <Product key={"1"} name={SchoolProduct.name} description={SchoolProduct.description}
    />
));
```

Or destructure immediately:

```
const OurProducts = SchoolProducts.map(({ name, description }) => (
  <Product key={"1"} name={name} description={description}
    />
));
```

(you can avoid making these sorts of mistakes by enforcing the [no-shadow](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow) ESLint rule)

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now. I will make sure to use different variables later on.

Comment: Can you explain me why i need the product.js file then?

Comment: Its just an component and nothing else can it be used to?

Comment: That's where your component is defined. You need the component in order to create the `OurProducts`, and you need that for the app to render.

Comment: I see. One last thing. Normally it would be {props.product.name} but {props.name} does work too? In some video i see people use the function name too

Comment: Oh yeah, that's an issue too. `product` isn't a property of props (if it were, you'd be passing it down like `SchoolProducts.map(SchoolProduct => <Product product={SchoolProduct}>`. But since the properties are *directly* on the props, the reference is an immediate child of `props`, rather than being further nested.

Comment: But when i want to say props.item.name then go to my App.js file and write item={SchoolProduct.name} then it says duplicate isnt aloud

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42367236 It sounds like you might have accidentally written a prop twice?